# How to make most of aws?

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding, amazon-ec2

I'm new to aws (just one day old). I'm impressed with aws free tier and want to utilize to its best. As of now I'm done with installing mongodb on aws micro instances and mongod EC2 instances are running fine. Now, I want to test my use case and unfortunately couldn't find much details on use case implementation related to mongodb shards, replica sets, traffic, load balancing, logs, cluster monitoring, metrics etc.,

It would be great if someone who has deployed mongodb databases on aws clusters and can share their tips and best practices here.

use case: I'm planning to deploy ProductCatalog and geojson apps on aws windows and linux micro instances.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has an excellent guide for deploying MongoDB on AWS.

https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_NoSQL_MongoDB.pdf

If you are looking for specific instructions on how do deploy MongoDB on AWS be sure to check this out:
https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/

Also bear in mind that AWS micro instances are too small for any production use of MongoDB. If your goal is simply learn MongoDB and AWS the micro instances maybe fine, but for any performance/stress testing the results for a micro  instance would not be realistic.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have tested micro instances on aws clusters? Have gone through the links, they are informative.